# Broadcast over all internet

Tags: broadcast

Is it possible for someone to send an IP broadcast packet over all internet?
I know that routers do not allow that, but is there any other way?

Comment: Imagine if someone could do this. Then I could just send broadcasts all day and overload everyone's internet connection. The internet wouldn't work. Does the internet work? Yes (mostly). Therefore I can't do this.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Broadcasts `(IP=255.255.255.255)` are not forwarded by routers.  Devices that do are called bridges or switches, not routers.

Directed broadcasts `(IP=192.0.2.255/24)` *could* be forwarded to a specific network, *if* the router was specifically configured to do so.  But routers on the Internet are never configured that way.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Broadcasts and multicasts are dropped all over the Internet.